# HTML / CSS / SVG - Responsive text and background

Tags: html, css, svg, text

I want to create a resizing svg 'container' (text and red background) which should be as big as the parent (blue background). I want the text and the background to resize. But I did not find a solution to resize text AND background.

Background resizes, text does not.

```
   <!-- Item 1 -->
      <div class="grid-item-container">
          <div class="grid-item">
              <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100% 100%">
                  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#c62828"></rect>
                  <text style="width: 100%; font-size: 20px;" x="0" y="20px" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white">Title</text>
              </svg>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Text resizes, background does not.

```
        <!-- Item 2 -->
       <div class="grid-item-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <!-- Content (svg) -->
                <svg class="svg-main" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#c62828"></rect>
                    <text style="font-size: 20px;" x="0" y="20px" width="100" height="100" fill="white">Resizing</text>
                </svg>
                <!-- Style (css) -->
                <div class="css-main">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/wYGmpd

Comment: but the background is a simple color? why SVG?

Comment: Use `viewbox="0 0 100 100"`not `viewbox="0 0 100% 100%"`

Comment: This is only for testing. I want to test if the simple color background fits the parent size. When I use this viewBox, the text text alignment is not on the very left of the container. I did not get it why the rect and text are centered horizonally.